# Error after installing scala plugin of netbeans

Tags: netbeans, scala, plugins

I installed the scala plugin on my netbeans and followed the instruction of this page: 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala68v1#Scala_Plugins_for_NetBeans_6.8_v1.x_.28RC2.29

but after it completed correctly step by step, when I make an empty project (Hello world!), the project has an error!
The empty project is here:

```
package scalaapplication1

object Main {
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

and the console error report is:

...\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:403: The following error occurred while executing this line:

...\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:236: scalac doesn't support the "fork" attribute

Is there any suggestion about it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Scala 2.7.7. After installing 2.8.0.RC1 it worked fine.

Henri